# OpenId authentication and automatic registration with Spring Security 3.0.2

Tags: spring, authentication, openid, spring-security, registration

I'm implementing an app using spring security 3.0.2 with OpenId login and registration.
I can login succesfully, but if the user isn't registered i want to do:

1) Get some OpenId attributes like email and name. 
2) Show to the user a registration form with just these two fields and the OpenId URI filled.

I've been searching a lot but i didn't find an "ellegant" way of doing this.
I wonder if some of u can come out with a solution to implement this strategy in my app.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

You can't show the email and name before the user has registered/login himself, since he has to allow the app to access his profile first. You can show him this page with his openid, mail etc *after* he logged in.

Define which attributes you want to use:

```
<openid-login login-page="/openidlogin.jsp" authentication-failure-url="/openidlogin.jsp?login_error=true">
  <attribute-exchange>
    <openid-attribute name="email" type="http://schema.openid.net/contact/email" required="true" count="2"/>
    <openid-attribute name="name" type="http://schema.openid.net/namePerson/friendly" />
  </attribute-exchange>
</openid-login>
```

And then access the attributes, after the user has logged in:

```
OpenIDAuthenticationToken token = (OpenIDAuthenticationToken)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
List<OpenIDAttribute> attributes = token.getAttributes();
```

Have a look at the [example from the spring repository](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/security/spring-security-samples-openid/3.0.1.RELEASE/spring-security-samples-openid-3.0.1.RELEASE.war), and the [OpenId Support Documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/ns-config.html#ns-openid).

Comment: @dude  : I have the similar problem and have used the answer suggested by you... but the code doesnt seem working.... have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7228733/openid-attribute-exchange-is-not-working-spring-security

Answer (score 0):

That is not implemented in Spring security < 3.1

However you can use a workaround with apectJ. Define the following aspect:

```
package org.acoveo.spring.utils;
@Aspect
public class OpenIDSpringAuthenticationHackAspect {
    static ThreadLocal<Authentication> authHolder = new ThreadLocal<Authentication>();
    @Around(value="execution(* org.springframework.security.openid.OpenIDAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(..))")
    public Object around(ProceedingJoinPoint jp) throws Throwable {
        try {
            Authentication auth = (Authentication) jp.getArgs()[0];
            authHolder.set(auth);
            Object returnVal = jp.proceed();
            authHolder.set(null);
            return returnVal;
        }catch(Throwable e) {
            System.out.println("Exception while running OpenIDSpringAuthenticationHackAspect");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
    public static Authentication getTransientAuthentication() {
        return authHolder.get();
    }
}
```

and register it in your aop.xml:

```
<!DOCTYPE aspectj PUBLIC "-//AspectJ//DTD//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/dtd/aspectj.dtd">  
<aspectj>
    <weaver options="-showWeaveInfo -verbose" />
    <weaver>
        <include within="org.springframework.security.openid..*" />
        <!-- This is required to make the spring instrument javaagent work with hibernate CGLIB
         -->
        <exclude within="*..*CGLIB*" />
    </weaver>
    <aspects>
        <aspect name="org.acoveo.spring.utils.OpenIDSpringAuthenticationHackAspect" />
    </aspects>
</aspectj>
```

Then in your UserDetailsService, you can access the OpenID attributes as follows:

```
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username, boolean includeTemporary) throws UsernameNotFoundException, DataAccessException {
    Authentication auth = OpenIDSpringAuthenticationHackAspect.getTransientAuthentication();
    if(auth != null && auth instanceof OpenIDAuthenticationToken) {
        // First try to find the user by their openid email address
        OpenIDAuthenticationToken openIdToken = (OpenIDAuthenticationToken)auth;
        String email = null;
        for(OpenIDAttribute attr : openIdToken.getAttributes()) {
            if("email".equals(attr.getName()) && attr.getValues() != null && !attr.getValues().isEmpty()) {
                email = attr.getValues().get(0);
                break;
            }
        }
        // TODO retrieve and return user
```

Comment: Remember that you still need to tell spring that you want the email attribute using the **<attribute-exchange>** tag.