# How to implement openId java web based application?

Tags: java, openid

In my web application i want to implement the OpenId just like stackoverflow.com have to login to its web-site.

In details you find while login to stackoverflow.com [image]

So when if one choose google then it allow the uses to log in through google account.

Please tell me how to implement it in java web application in details. Is there any single api for login through different website like(yahoo,google,facebook,etc)

Thanks

Comment: I asked the same question a while ago:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571384/is-there-a-spring-security-openid-registration-like-stackoverflow

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not quite. Most of the ones you have mentioned simply use the OpenID protocol, however Facebook uses its own authorisation, so you would need to add that as a separate method.

Take a look at [OpenID4Java](https://github.com/jbufu/openid4java)

I have also used the [openid-selector](https://code.google.com/p/openid-selector/) for the client side part.

Finally, I would take a look at the [this resource](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Openid#OpenID_Providers) to see the URL endpoints for the different providers.

Answer (score 7):

There is two sides of this:

- client-side. This is the easier part. You can do this manually, but there are already javascript solutions that will render a list of openid providers. Check [openid-selector](https://code.google.com/p/openid-selector/) and [this jQuery plugin](http://jvance.com/pages/JQueryOpenIDPlugin.xhtml). I personally like the latter more.
- server-side. You will have to handle openId authentication. There are multiple java libraries (they are all listed on the openid website). Here is one that I decided to use: [openid4java](https://github.com/jbufu/openid4java). See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071518/best-java-openid-library) for my motivation.